# fatal error: 'openssl/x509.h' file not found in Flutter iOS build after integrating firestore

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My Flutter app was integrated with Firebase and the app was building successfully with Firebase core and auth. However when I added the `cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0` dependency, the build fails on iOS (still works on Android) with the following error message:

```
In file included from /Users/charismak/AndroidStudioProjects/foodstack/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/xds/xds_channel_secure.cc:34:
    In file included from /Users/charismak/AndroidStudioProjects/foodstack/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:35:
    In file included from /Users/charismak/AndroidStudioProjects/foodstack/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security_connector.h:33:
    /Users/charismak/AndroidStudioProjects/foodstack/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.h:28:10: fatal error: 'openssl/x509.h' file not found
    #include <openssl/x509.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

When I remove the dependency, it builds successfully.

I have tried running `pod install`, `flutter clean`, changing the deployment target on Xcode and podfile, and installing/upgrading openssl.

It is the same issue as this: [Not found 'openssl/x509.h' when install cloud_firesore flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892912/not-found-openssl-x509-h-when-install-cloud-firesore-flutter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it by running the following commands in terminal inside <your_project_path>/ios:

```
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock

pod cache clean --all

pod install
```

(Installation may take some time to complete)

Source: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3203#issuecomment-743789416