# Could not build the application for the simulator. (M1 chip)

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-m1

I am on m1 apple chip and I am trying to run my flutter app on iphone 11 device but I am getting this error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            3.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[62383]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ec79d160) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113e102b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[62383]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1ec79d1b0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113e10308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/xds/xds_channel_secure.cc:34:
    In file included from /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.h:35:
    In file included from /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security_connector.h:33:
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.h:28:10: fatal error: 'openssl/x509.h' file not found
    #include <openssl/x509.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/roeeattias/Desktop/mybarber_ios/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Someone know how do I fix this ?

Comment: fatal error: 'openssl/x509.h' file not found

Comment: what is that mean

Comment: It might be a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822031/fatal-error-openssl-x509-h-file-not-found-in-flutter-ios-build-after-integrat

Answer (score 0):

Change architecture in target from ARCHS_STANDART to x86_64 and it will be work (This solution working for me)